# I am not getting Postion of the BlockReference?

Tags: python-2.7, autocad, autocad-plugin

when I try to make an excel sheet. which needs AdcblockReference name and position. but when I try to run this code getting attribute error. so I don't  how to get the position and name below given is my code

```
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlrd
import xlwt
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
import os
import win32com.client
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
from pyautocad.contrib.tables import Table
from comtypes import COMError

# Create workbook
book = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = book.add_sheet("ExportedData")
book.save("Exported.xls")

# Open the workbook
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Exported.xls")
sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()

xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])

wb = copy(xl_workbook)
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)

dwgfiles = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(os.curdir))

cwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)  # current working dir
print(cwd)
for f in dwgfiles:
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")

    print(f)
    if f.endswith(".dwg"):
        print("sdaasdas")
        """ open Document"""
        acad = Autocad()
        print(cwd)
        acad.app.Documents.open(cwd + "/" + f)

        print(acad.doc.Name)

        num_cols = xl_sheet.ncols  # Number of columns
        idx = 1

        acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")

        doc = acad.ActiveDocument  # Document object

        print("MODEL SPACE")
        count=0
        for entity in acad.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace:
            name = entity.EntityName
            print(name)
            if name == 'AcDbBlockReference':
                print(name)
                count=count+1
                sheet.row(idx).write(1, entity.ObjectID)
                sheet.row(idx).write(2, cwd + "/" + f)
                sheet.row(idx).write(3,entity.IntersectionPoint)
                idx = idx + 1

        print(count)
        doc.Close(False)
        acad = None
wb.save("Exported.xls")
```

below is the error am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto1.py", line 64, in <module>
    sheet.row(idx).write(3,entity.IntersectionPoint)
  File "D:\autocad_test\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.IntersectionPoint
```

its very helpful if you suggest me any good tutorial of python on AutoCAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be typing mistake.
You use  `IntersectionPoint` while the correct should be `InsertionPoint` as in VBA or maybe `position` as in ObjectARX

Comment: Thanks its worked. I do have 1 more dought , How to get BlockReference Name and Cordinate .

Comment: I'm not working with pyton, so I'm not sure. But in VBA BlockReference has property Name, or method GetName.
In ObjectARX You need to get BlockDefinition, and read name form BlockDefinition

Comment: and what You mean by "Cordinate"? isn't InsertionPoint exactly Coordinates

Comment: @ CAD Developer: yes thank you. do you have any link of VBA tutorial?

Comment: I'm using ZWCAD where just press F1 to get help with many examples.

By the way: would You accept the answer? I like reputation very much ;)